# A problem with the protractor

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

How to set the protractor to measure the  `A,C,B`  angle?

[image: the protractor problem]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 6/0/B, 3/3/C}
\tkzDrawPolygon[draw=red,very thick,fill=red,fill opacity=.4](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
%\tkzDrawCircle[in](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzProtractor[with=half](C,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this? I don't understand which angle do you want to measure.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 6/0/B, 3/3/C}
\tkzDrawPolygon[draw=red,very thick,fill=red,fill opacity=.4](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
%\tkzDrawCircle[in](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzProtractor[with=half](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

If you want to measure the right angle, add `return` (or `rotate`) to `proactor` options:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 6/0/B, 3/3/C}
\tkzDrawPolygon[draw=red,very thick,fill=red,fill opacity=.4](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
%\tkzDrawCircle[in](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzProtractor[with=half, return](C,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP says "angle ACB", ie the one at the top...

Comment: Yes, @Thruston is right. I want to measure the right angle.

Comment: So try: `\tkzProtractor[with=half](C,A)`

Comment: @ostal123 I've updated the answer. Is it better now?