# tikz - draw several separators in an arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I tried to paint a protractor. But am not able to paint some kind of separators along the arc. Especially the smaler radius seems to be a problem for me :(

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[color=black] (1,1)--(5,1)--(5,1.5)--(4.5,1.5) arc[radius = 1.5, start angle = 0, end angle = 180]--(1,1.5)--(1,1);
\draw (4,1.5) arc[radius = 1, start angle = 0, end angle = 180]--(4,1.5);

\foreach \angle in {0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}  {
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I change the position of the scale, up to the arc and change the size of the separator-arc?

the final picture should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Centre the protractor so the base of the arc is at `(0,0)` or use a `shift` when adding the angles. Use something like `1.3cm` and `1.5cm` rather than `1.8cm` and `2cm` if your largest arc is 1.5cm. Or make the largest arc 2cm.

Comment: A nice protractor with tikz from @Ignasi: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283150/31034

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: enter code here]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black] (1,1)--(5,1)--(5,1.5)--(4.5,1.5) arc[radius = 1.5, start angle = 0, end angle = 180]--(1,1.5)--(1,1);
    \draw (4,1.5) arc[radius = 1, start angle = 0, end angle = 180]--(4,1.5);

\foreach \angle in {0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}  {
\draw[red,line width=1pt] (3,1.5) ++ (\angle:1.3cm) -- ++  (\angle:0.2);% <-- changed
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

At polar coordinates, if you not define starting point, starts from coordinate (0,0). Therefore in above solution the starting point is shifted by `(3,1.5) ++ (\angle:1.3cm)` and also used relative positioning with `-- '' (-- ++  (\angle:0.2);`.

Another possible solution is redraw protractor so that starting point is at begin of arc instead of its below left corner: see answer of @cfr.

Off-topic: in drawing of arc you can use shorter notation: `(<start angle>:<end angle>:<radious>)`, for example:

```
\draw   (1.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) -| ++ (-0.5,-0.5) -| ++ (4,0.5) -- cycle;
\draw   (1.0,0) arc (0:180:1) -- cycle;
```

(where is assumed, that drawing of "separators" is done by:

```
\foreach \angle in {0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}  
{
\draw   (\angle:1.3cm) -- ++  (\angle:0.2);
}
```

**Addendum:**
for fun:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (1.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) -| ++ (-0.5,-0.5) -| ++ (4,0.5) -- cycle;
\draw   (1.0,0) arc (0:180:1) -- cycle;

\foreach \angle in {0, 30,...,180}  
{
\draw   (\angle:1.25) node[font=\tiny,sloped,rotate=-90+\angle] {\angle} 
                     ++ (\angle:0.1) -- ++  (\angle:0.15);
}
\foreach \angle in {0, 10,...,180}
{
\draw   (\angle:1.4) -- ++  (\angle:0.1);
}

\draw (0,0) -- ++ (0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks. Thats exactly what i wanted :) But what stands the notation   -| ++  for? Is this a short notation for a vertical/horizontal line?

Comment: yes. it roughly said, means "draw line horizontally and than vertically relative to previous coordinate for amount given in coordinate which follows".

Answer (score 4):

By default, polar coordinates start drawing centered at `(0,0)`, so, you need to shift the separators by `(3cm,1.5cm)` to move to the new center. This is easily achieved in a `scope`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[color=black] (1,1)--(5,1)--(5,1.5)--(4.5,1.5)coordinate(o) arc[radius = 1.5, start angle = 0, end angle = 180]--(1,1.5)--(1,1);
\draw (4,1.5) arc[radius = 1, start angle = 0, end angle = 180]--(4,1.5);

\begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,1.5cm)}]
\foreach \angle in {0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.5cm) -- (\angle:1.3cm);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

If you centre the base of the arcs on `(0,0)`, then adding the marks etc. is easier. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1.5,0) arc[radius = 1.5, start angle = 0, end angle = 180] -| ++(-.5,-.5) -| ++(4,.5) --cycle;
\draw (1,0) arc[radius = 1, start angle = 0, end angle = 180] -- cycle;

\foreach \angle in {0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}  {
\draw [line width=1pt] (\angle:1.3cm) -- (\angle:1.5cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: protractor]

Comment: ups, my second example (added later) is almost the same as your example. I will erase it ...

Answer (score 3):

Just for comparison with the Tikz solutions, here's one I did earlier in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) + [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    color plastic; plastic = 1/256(215,205,190);

    path lower_base, upper_base, inner_arc, outer_arc;

    upper_base = (left--right) scaled 5.2 cm;
    lower_base = upper_base shifted (0,-1.6cm);
    inner_arc = halfcircle scaled 5.4cm;
    outer_arc = halfcircle scaled 8.8cm;

    % make the plastic body
    fill lower_base -- point 1 of upper_base -- outer_arc -- point 0 of upper_base -- cycle withcolor plastic;
    unfill inner_arc -- cycle;

    % draw the scale along the base
    for t = 0 upto 100:
       x := 50-t;
       draw (origin -- if x mod 10 = 0: 8 elseif x mod 5 = 0: 6 else: 5 fi up) shifted (x*mm, ypart point 0 of lower_base);
       if x mod 10 = 0:
         label.top(decimal (t/10) infont defaultfont scaled 0.7
         rotated 180, (x*mm,ypart point 0 of lower_base + 9)); 
       fi
    endfor

    % and the scale around the arc
    for t = 0 upto 180:
       draw (origin -- if t mod 10=0: 16 elseif t mod 5=0: 12 else: 8 fi left)
            shifted point 0 of outer_arc rotated t;
       if t mod 10=0:
          if t=90:
              label("90" infont defaultfont scaled 1.4, 26 down shifted point 2 of outer_arc);
          else:
              label(decimal       t infont defaultfont scaled 0.7 rotated (t-90), 22 left shifted point 0 of outer_arc rotated t);
              label(decimal (180-t) infont defaultfont scaled 0.7 rotated (t-90), 30 left shifted point 0 of outer_arc rotated t)
              withcolor .78 red;
          fi
       fi
    endfor

    % finally mark the middle
    draw origin -- 4 down;
    unfill fullcircle scaled 2;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```